# Where can I find release notes/changelog for ubuntu AWS AMIs?

Tags: aws

How can I find changelog between two AWS ubuntu images released in this site?

https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/

Comment: Are you looking for the *difference* between two images? If so, which images? A *changelog* is only between successive versions on the same branch, not between different regional images.

Comment: I am looking for what is changed between 20190807 and 20190816 release?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/).
According to the links in the page I suspect that AWS gets the images from here.

[image]

At the bottom of the page, there is a list called "Release Images".
In it is a list of directories, each for a specific release of Ubuntu (Both by number and by name).

[image]

In each directory is a list of releases for that version of Ubuntu, and at the bottom of each release directory is another directory called "unpacked".
In that directory is a file called "release_notes.txt". That has what you're looking for, I think.
[For example](http://cloud-images-archive.ubuntu.com/releases/bionic/release-20190306/unpacked/release_notes.txt)

**Note**
In some of the less current releases you'll get a "403 Forbidden" error when accessing the "Unpacked" directory.
Even in those if you just slap "release_notes.txt" at the end of the address bar it will still work.

Comment: @Kulfy, added in main answer.